# Echo in preaction Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm trying to find the output of `echo 'hello world'` which I added to - edit scheme -> Build -> pre-action -> add run script, in Xcode.

I've tried to find it in the build in the "report navigator" sector but it's not there.

[image]

Where can I find my 'hello world' output from a pre-action?

Answer (score 2):

I ended up creating a file and write the log in it.

```
exec > "${PROJECT_DIR}/prebuild.log" 2>&1
echo "Starting build scheme Pre-actions"
```

I found this answer in stack.

Run the preaction a couple of times and you will see "prebuild.log" file in the project directory in finder - every echo will be written there. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

View -> Navigators -> Reports (Cmd + 9) -> local tab

Pre actions are at the beginning. Then you must click on this little funny icon on the right side of the screen.

[image]

Scroll down and there it is :)

[image]

Comment: Fails to understand the question.

Comment: No, I did understand the question which was "Where can I find my 'hello world' output from a pre-action?" The output is in reports collapsed. This icon expands the whole output.